# How to verify a curl request in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, http, curl

I have a curl request like this :

```
curl -s -u $user:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url
```

Which returns a json as response. So I will parse the response using jq to get some specific data. Like this :

```
curl -s -u $user:$password -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" $url | jq '<expression>'
```

Now if the curl request fails then obviously the parsing operation throws ugly error. I want to avoid this. How to store the response first and then later parse it if the request is successful. I don't want to display the json whole response. Also if I add `-w "%{http_code}"` in my request it appends the status code with the JSON response which messes up the parsing. How to solve this ? I basically want to first check if the curl request is successful or not then get the JSON response and parse it.I also want to get the status code, so that if it fails I can display the status code. But status code is now messing up with json response.

Comment: Unrelated nit: you probably meant to say "Accept:", not "Content-Type".

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the `--write` and `--fail` options:

```
# separating the (verbose) curl options into an array for readability
curl_args=(
  --write "%{http_code}\n"
  --fail
  --silent
  --user "$user:$password"
  --request GET
  --header "Content-Type: application/json"
)

if ! output=$(curl "${curl_args[@]}" "$url"); then
    echo "Failure: code=$output"
else
    # remove the "http_code" line from the end of the output, and parse it
    sed '$d' <<<"$output" | jq '...'
fi
```

Also note: [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)!

Comment: Why do you need the `http_code`, if you trust `--fail` to exit with a failure on an error (4xx or 5xx response)?

Comment: Nicely done; I suggest `sed '$d'`, because it is portable (`Q` is a GNU-specific function). @CharlesDuffy: Note that `--silent` suppresses the error message normally output by `--fail`, which would include the status code, but `--silent` is needed to suppress the progress meter.

Answer (score 1):

I found glenn jackman's answer good, but a bit confusingly written, so I rewrote it, and altered it so I can use it as a safer alternative to `curl | jq`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# call this with normal curl arguments, especially url argument, e.g.
# safecurl.sh "http://example.com:8080/something/"
# separating the (verbose) curl options into an array for readability
curl_args=(
  -H 'Accept:application/json'
  -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
  --write '\n%{http_code}\n'
  --fail
  --silent
)
echo "${curl_args[@]}"
# prepend some arguments, but pass on whatever arguments this script was called with
output=$(curl "${curl_args[@]}" "$@")
return_code=$?
if [ 0 -eq $return_code ]; then
    # remove the "http_code" line from the end of the output, and parse it
    echo "$output" | sed '$d' | jq .
else
    # echo to stderr so further piping to jq will process empty output
    >&2 echo "Failure: code=$output"
fi
```

Note: This code does not test for services that ignore the requested content type and respond with HTML. You'd need to test for `grep -l '</html>'` for that.